# Low Cost Motorized Valve

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor

I'm looking for a low cost motorized water valve.  I've done a number of searches and have found nothing compelling.  Has anyone here used a motorized water valve with Arduino?  What would you recommend?

A fail-open solenoid might also work but I'd like to try my hand at a motorized valve.

The valves I found start at US$50.  I'm looking for something cheaper.  The purpose is tinkering and I'd like to make an "if water detected - then close valve" sketch.  Ir's simple, just more expensive than I expected.

Comment: This is not Arduino-specific. You may find [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) useful for this question.  More-specific questions are more answerable.

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you didn't like about the valves that you found – that would help folks trying to answer understand more about what you want. Specifying what you mean by low cost and what the valve needs to manage (type of liquid, size, operation speed) would also make for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get sprinkler valves, that use solenoids, for under $20 that fit on plastic PVC pipe and are designed for water, such as these at [SprinklerWarehouse](http://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/).  They typically use pipe sizes of about 1 inch.

Comment: Right, but I'm looking for a motorized valve or a fail-open solenoid.  I think the lawn stuff is fail-closed.